# Replace column string name with another column value in Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following dataframe with a column `sig` and `N` other columns.

`sig` contains `N` number of column embedded into it as shown below. The embedded column names can be of any number present in the dataframe.

I want to update the `sig` column with the corresponding values from the other columns.

For example,

```text
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+------------------+-------------------+--------+
|sig                                                                  |order_timing|po_manl_create_ind|mabd_arrival_status|cut_time|
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+------------------+-------------------+--------+
|R1:BR1-order_timing:BR2-po_manl_create_ind:BR3-mabd_arrival_status:R1|14          |0                 |late               |23      |
|R1:BR1-order_timing:BR2-po_manl_create_ind:BR7-cut_time:R1           |14          |0                 |on_time            |10      |
```

**Expected output**

```text
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+-----
|sig                        |order_timing|po_manl_create_ind|mabd_arrival_status|cut_time|
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+-----
|R1:BR1-14:BR2-0:BR3-late:R1|14          |0                 |late               |23      |
|R1:BR1-14:BR2-0:BR7-10:R1  |14          |0                 |on_time            |10      |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to chain multiple [`replace`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/sql/#replace) expressions by using the list of columns likely to be present in `sig` values.

Using this sample DF:

```scala
val df = Seq(
   ("R1:BR1-order_timing:BR2-po_manl_create_ind:BR3-mabd_arrival_status:R1", 14, 0, "late", 23),
   ("R1:BR1-order_timing:BR2-po_manl_create_ind:BR7-cut_time:R1", 14, 0, "on_time", 10),
).toDF("sig", "order_timing", "po_manl_create_ind", "mabd_arrival_status", "cut_time")
```

You can generate the replacement expression `replace_expr` using foldLeft like this:

```scala
val replace_expr = df.columns
  .filter(_ != "sig")
  .foldLeft("sig")((acc, c) => s"replace($acc, '$c', $c)")

df.withColumn("sig", expr(replace_expr)).show(false)

//+---------------------------+------------+------------------+-------------------+--------+
//|sig                        |order_timing|po_manl_create_ind|mabd_arrival_status|cut_time|
//+---------------------------+------------+------------------+-------------------+--------+
//|R1:BR1-14:BR2-0:BR3-late:R1|14          |0                 |late               |23      |
//|R1:BR1-14:BR2-0:BR7-10:R1  |14          |0                 |on_time            |10      |
//+---------------------------+------------+------------------+-------------------+--------+
```

Comment: Awesome, looks like magic! Only issue is entire sig value becomes NULL if any of the column contains NULL.

Comment: @Shaun you can use [`nvl`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#nvl) function to handle cases when replacement value is null. Simply modify the expression to: `s"replace($acc, '$c', nvl($c, ''))"` this will put empty string in case of null.